# Why is my every column in pandas dataframe a numpy object instead of float?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I read a tsv file into a dataframe and do log transformations using np.log function but even after a correct transformation, while doing ttest with scipy, it gives an error because the columns are numpy objects and not float.

```
master_data.iloc[:,:] = master_data.iloc[:,:].applymap(lambda x: np.log(x+1))
```

I even run PCA after this and runs fine and plots on seaborn as well.

I accidentally deleted a virtual environment I was working on and all the packages are now lost. I am installing each and everyone now and I tried to go back to their stable versions but the problem still persists.

Comment: `master_data.dtypes`?

Comment: what error? exactly, not summarized

Comment: `np.log` does produce a `float64` or array of the same, depending on what `x` is.  So what?

Comment: After i do log transformation, the columns still show up as numpy.object. With previous environment( i don't know which versions were present but it got deleted), I ran the same script and it worked perfectly but now i have to typecast my df for it to work. So what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that some of the column data types in your dataframe are `object` instead of numerical, causing `numpy` to fail. You can see the datatypes by running `print(master_data.dtypes)`.

A fix that usually works for me is to let `pandas` automatically convert the `object` types to numerical types: `master_data = master_data.infer_objects()`. This usually does a good job of appropriately converting column data types to numerical ones. If this doesn't fix it, and you need to force datatypes to be numerical where possible, you can add `.astype`, i.e. `master_data = master_data.infer_objects().astype(np.float64, errors='ignore')` (or `errors='raise'` to halt execution).